# C creates extra bytes in buffer

Tags: c

I've been messing around with C today and don't understand the difference in outputs when I comment out the third buffer in this code:

```
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 void main() {
     unsigned char letters[10];
    memset(letters, 0x00, 10);
    memset(letters, 0x41, 10);
    printf(letters);
    printf(" Total buffer len: %d bytes\n",strlen(letters));

     char nletters[10];
    memset(nletters, 0x00, 10);
    memset(nletters, 0x42, 10);
     printf(nletters);
    printf(" Total buffer len: %d bytes\n",strlen(nletters));

     int nums[10];
     memset(nums, 0x00, 10);
    memset(nums, 0x43, 10);
    printf(nums);
    printf(" Total buffer len: %d bytes\n",strlen(nums));   
 return 0;
}
```

The difference is with comments removed around the nums buffer:

```
AAAAAAAAAA�7ǝ�U Total buffer len: 16 bytes
BBBBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAA�7ǝ�U Total buffer len: 26 bytes
```

And with the buffer left in:

```
AAAAAAAAAA Total buffer len: 10 bytes
BBBBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAA Total buffer len: 20 bytes
CCCCCCCCCC��U Total buffer len: 14 bytes
```

What I don't get is:

1. How can commenting out the third buffer affect the size of the others?
2. What are the extra bytes at the end of the buffers and how can I lose/manage them (if I choose to concatenate the buffers)?
3. Why are the differences in the printed buffer size and initialized size not consistent when I choose whether to comment the third buffer?
4. Buffer 2 is supposed to be 10 bytes, why is it 20? I don't want it to be 20, I only asked for 10. I don't think that's unreasonable.

Comment: You've just had a major run-in with the bête noir of C programmers — _undefined behaviour_.  You're not working with null-terminated strings, so when you treat them as null terminated strings, you get weird effects.  Your `printf(nums)` should have yielded shrieks of protest from your compiler — heed it; it was trying to help you.  (If you're using `<unistd.h>`, using `void main()` is wrong too.  See [What should `main()` return in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/) for the sordid details.)

Answer (score 2):

`char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated*** byte strings. That *null-terminated* bit is important, and all string functions look for it to know when the string ends.

If you pass an unterminated string to a string function, it will go out of bounds and that will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The terminator is equal to zero, either integer `0` or the character `'\0'`.

And of course this null-terminator character needs space in your string. That means a string of 10 character must have space for 11 to fit the terminator.

The simple first would look something like

```
char letters[11] = { 0 };  // Space for ten character plus terminator
// The above definition also initializes all elements in the array to zero,
// which is the terminator character

memset(letters, 'A', 10);  // Set the ten first characters to the letter 'A'

printf("%s", letters);  // Never print a data string directly using printf's first parameter.

printf(" Total buffer len: %d bytes\n", strlen(letters));
```

<sub>Note the change to `printf`. This is because if you ever get the string input from a user, passing it directly as the format string to `printf` is an incredibly bad security hole. If the string contains formatting code but there are no arguments, that would lead to *undefined behavior*.</sub>

<sub>Also note that I changed the [*magic number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) `0x41` to the [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) character it corresponds to. Magic numbers is a bad habit that makes code harder to read, understand and maintain.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
memset(letters, 0x00, 10);
memset(letters, 0x41, 9);   /* <--- see the array size minus one there */
```

that will make the `printf(3)` to work properly, but printing a list of nine `A`s only.  As explained in other responses, this has to do with the nightmare for C programmers to null terminate strings built by hand. For that reason is more common to use the `<string.h>` functions.

In another place, using `printf()`'s first parameter without a string literal is discouraged, as in the case your string had a `%` character, that would be interpreted as a format descriptor, and you would had run into more Undefined behaviour, again.